# How can I pass a jQuery element to a JavaScript function without an id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

html:

```
<div class="myClass">abc</div>
<div class="myClass">def</div>
<div class="myClass">ghi</div>
<div class="myClass">jkl</div>
<div class="myClass">mno</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.myClass').on('click',function() {
    // do stuff in jQuery ...
    // also select text using a pure JavaScript function like so:
    selectElementText(el);
    // obviously a `$(this)` won't work.
    // A `document.getElementById('myId')` will work, but I don't know how to get it
});
```

javascript select text function (via https://stackoverflow.com/a/2838358/834525):

```
function selectElementText(el, win) {
    win = win || window;
    var doc = win.document, sel, range;
    if (win.getSelection && doc.createRange) {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

How can I pass a document element to this function?

Comment: `selectElementText(this);` ???

Comment: Can you also show the element whos text you want to select? Or is it the element the user just clicked? If so, @A.Wolff's suggestion is exactly what you need.

Comment: `obviously a $(this) won't work` - actually, it will (but all you need to pass is `this`)

Comment: @A.Wolff comes to the rescue again! Truth be told I just figured it out as I hit refresh, but you got it submitted before then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

`selectElementText(this);`

To pass DOM node as parameter to `selectElementText()` function. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using the `document` keyword:

```
 selectElementText(document, window);
                     ^         ^        
                     ^          --- the window as in case of the function (optional)
                     ^--- the document as an argument which you want to pass
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @A. Wolff, it should be `selectElementText(this);`

Comment: My first thought reading `document element` in question, but then doesn't make sense regarding function code

Comment: @A.Wolff Now that I look more carefully, I see you are right. Editing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `this`, instead of `$(this)`  Like so: `selectElementText(this);`